# Will Wordpress use the newer schedule if it is updated using the filter 'cron_schedules'?

Tags: cron

I learned that you can add new cron schedules by using the [cron_schedules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules) filter. If I change a interval of a schedule that I added earlier, will a job that uses this schedule be scheduled using this new interval the next time, or will it still use the previous interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I figured out that yes, it will use the new schedule, updated using the 'cron_schedules' filter.